# Why is the gtk_render_check result not what I expect?

Tags: gtk, gtkmm

I'm trying to implement the [Selection mode](https://developer.gnome.org/hig/stable/selection-mode.html.en) UI pattern in my application.

A problem that was immediately apparent is that there is no default implementation for this kind of view, and that each application that implements it does so in a different way.

I already have a view implemented using GtkFlowBox, so my plan was to overlay a widget containing the checkmark over each child widget (a thumbnail, in my case).

I first tried using a GtkCheckButton, but it won't suit me, since I can't control its size.

I then decided to render the checkmark to a GtkImage using [gtk_render_check](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStyleContext.html#gtk-render-check). I picked it up from gnome-todo, while practically copying the code used for that ([gnome-todo's code](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-todo/blob/3.28.1/src/views/gtd-list-selector-grid-item.c#L263), [my code](https://github.com/junrrein/pdfslicer/blob/selection-mode/src/ui/pagewidget.cpp#L76)).

[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gdsvm.png) (my app on the left, gnome-todo on the right).

As you can see, in my app the checkmarks are very blurry, but otherwise have the same dimensions and aspect of the checkmarks in gnome-todo.

What could be causing this?

**Update**: I run the same code using the Adwaita theme, and the difference between gnome-todo and my application is pretty big.

[Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jsvQ.png). What could be causing the results to be so dissimilar?

**Update 2**: Using styleContext->set_scale(int scale) solves the problem of the result being blurry, but the aspect of the result is still the same as in the last screenshot.

Comment: Gnome-todo seems to be adjusting the surface size based on scale-factor and you aren't: if you are using a high-DPI screen to compare the results, this might explain the results

Comment: @jku I'm using a standard-DPI screen. The scale factor returned by gtk_widget_get_scale_factor is 1.But this could become a problem for high-DPI screens, once I fix this issue, so I'll have it in mind.

Comment: @jku I added a screenshot of the same situation using the Adwaita theme. Now the results are completely different.